# EPG Layout like androidtv livetv app

Tags: android, android-tv, iptv, epg

We are developing the EPG layout for android tv app but our app does not implement the TIF completely

Can we use only EPG layout from TIF and render it on my app?

Any ideas, please suggest

Thanks

Comment: How did you implement the EPG layout? Did you build a custom RecyclerView LayoutManager?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the source code of Live Channels (EPG layout included) here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/+/android-live-tv

Please keep in mind that if you are third party developer, you can not access all EPG data. `com.android.providers.tv.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EPG_DATA` permission is only granted to system app.

Answer (score 1):

We have created a library based on the source code of the Android Live Channels app (the source code linked in the other answer):

https://github.com/egeniq/android-tv-program-guide

It does not use the EPG data as the official app does, but you can supply your own channels and programs. (Although building a connector from the TV EPG data to this library should be fairly simple).

Comment: Hi @Daniel, is there a way to load EPG data in a paginated API call in this library?

Comment: @Sakib if you paginate the data per days, then yes. If per channels, then no, you will need the data of all channels for a specific day to load them into the EPG

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code of Live Channels (EPG layout included) here:
https://github.com/PerfsolTech/EPGView

- Display TV schedule as a grid.
- Support for various EPG data sources (Mapping XML, JSON, API to library model).
- Customizable design and styling.
- Program search and filtering capabilities.
- Easy integration into your Android TV or mobile application.
- Supporting D-Pad and touch (or mouse) scrolling